# Wild Flash Graphics, Bro!

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, english

I've had many tricks played on me, but to my credit, I'm rarely so green anymore.

I used to pack quite a punch, things even got spicy with a mom.

I'll post a video greeting if and only if I'm in Wales.

Calling me Jack is sound, but what's my real ID?

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm going to lay this one down:

> card

I've had many tricks played on me, but to my credit, I'm rarely so green anymore.

> Card tricks with playing cards, credit card, and green cards are scarcer with Trump.

I used to pack quite a punch, things even got spicy with a mom.

> A pack of cards, a punch (or punched) card used for computer code entry, card*amom* is a spice.

I'll post a video greeting if and only if I'm in Wales.

> Postcard, video card, greeting card, and *card* + *iff* → Cardiff the Welsh capital.

Calling me Jack is sound, but what's my real ID?

> A calling card, a jack is one of you, a sound card and an ID card.

Note to report on the suitable number of words the puzzle is carrying:

> I count 52 words in this story - a full deck!

Title: Wild Flash Graphics, Bro!

> Wild card, flash card, graphics card and courtesy of *Chowzen* the *bro card* which you can use occasionally with a good bro.

Comment: Dude, I'm gonna have to play my "brocard" and ask you not to date my ex-girlfriend.

Comment: Forget @Chowzen, you can date mine.  Just give me your calling card and I'll pass it along!  Maybe send a postcard from your honeymoon?

Comment: rot13(Terra pneqf nera'g irel terra, gurl unir irel yvggyr bs gung pbybe ba gurz. Unf abguvat gb qb jvgu Gehzc :C)

Comment: Yup, that covers everything, it seems. (I may have meant the first ”bro” you had, but Chowzen’s one works nicely enough.) Congrats on the 20k!

Comment: Thank you Bass for such a definite question, having like 18 naturally concealed clues  - which took numerous attempts to find!

Comment: @Tom Your comment made me wonder about the clue density of the puzzle, so I counted the words (excluding the title), and realized I absolutely had to add one more clue :-)